# Ollama connection refused - on 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux

Can help me?

```
[root@llama2 system]# curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{
  "model": "llama2",
  "prompt":"Why is the sky blue?"
}'
```

I installed Llama with support for the Nvidia GPU, installation via script is automatic, I run llama pull, and at the end every time I try to run curl I get the error below:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

If execute telnet:

```
[root@llama2 system]# telnet localhost 11434
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

IPtables:

```
[root@llama2 system]# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Logs from `systemctl` status:

```
[root@llama2 system]# systemctl status ollama.service 
● ollama.service - Ollama Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ollama.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-01-11 02:21:03 UTC; 5min ago
 Main PID: 46392 (ollama)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 63452)
   Memory: 399.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ollama.service
           └─46392 /usr/local/bin/ollama serve

Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 systemd[1]: ollama.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 systemd[1]: Stopped Ollama Service.
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 systemd[1]: Started Ollama Service.
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 images.go:808: total blobs: 6
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 images.go:815: total unused blobs removed: 0
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 routes.go:930: Listening on 127.0.0.1:11434 (version 0.1.19)
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 shim_ext_server.go:142: Dynamic LLM variants [cuda rocm]
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 gpu.go:35: Detecting GPU type
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 gpu.go:54: Nvidia GPU detected
Jan 11 02:21:03 llama2 ollama[46392]: 2024/01/11 02:21:03 gpu.go:84: CUDA Compute Capability detected: 8.6
lines 3-19/19 (END)
```

Using rocky Linux 8.9 on VPS, I try on VMware and Citrix Censerver and it works!

I didn't do anything different, I just ran the script and executed the pull and the connection works, as we are talking about a loopback connection, is there anything I missed?

I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure from your error message and the telnet output, that the port is accessible and you are successfully connecting to it. that the response is empty is a application level issue, not an issue with network accessibility (TCP) or the webserver (HTTP). its just that the HTTP response you receive contains no data. you would get an error in telnet if you could not connect to the port, and you'd get a HTTP error if the webserver could not understand what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem as resource low. After upgrade ram to 20GB and GPU video to 8GB workings fine!

I see log CUDA Nvidia has stopped because don’t have resource to attempts start services.